# Nuxt: how can I get sourcemap files and where can I find them in production?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have tried alot of solutions (nuxt.config & change the devtool source-map) but nothing work..
I need to get the real source code in production so I can get the real error's line like Sentry for example
please can anyone help me...

Comment: Since it will be bundled for production, I'm not sure that you can do that. Can't you find it without the exact line?

Comment: @kissu it's just showing the error line of complied files
in Sentry it's showing the current error line when app in production mode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the example from the [NuxtJS documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#extend) for extending Webpack configuration in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    extend(config, { isClient }) {
      // Extend only webpack config for client-bundle
      if (isClient) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you then run `npm run build`, source maps (`*.js.map`) will have been generated under `.nuxt/dist/` and the bundled JS will reference them.

For example, a bundled JS named `.nuxt/dist/client/05439bf.js` will have a source map named `.nuxt/dist/client/05439bf.js.map` and contain a reference comment on its final line:

```js
//# sourceMappingURL=05439bf.js.map
```

If you then run the build with `npm run start`, and open the Sources tab in Chrome DevTools, you will now see a webpack:// tree in the Page hierarchy, showing the original source for the Nuxt app, i.e. pages, components, layouts, etc.

When you deploy the build to the production environment, ensure that the `*.js.map` files under `/.nuxt/dist/` are also deployed.